# Avoid same address for empty structs

Tags: go, pointers

In an attempt to have more useful enums in Go, I've tried using struct pointers as enum values. This works great if the struct has fields, but for the empty struct I sometimes get the same pointer multiple times, regardless of whether I use `&Foo{}` or `new(Foo)`.

Is there any way I can force the pointers to be different?

This is what I'm trying to do ([try it online](https://play.golang.org/p/0KumCPN3k0U)):

```go
package main

type Foo struct{}

var FooValues = struct {
    Alpha   *Foo
    Bravo   *Foo
    Charlie *Foo
}{
    Alpha:   &Foo{}, // These pointers should all be different
    Bravo:   &Foo{}, // But sometimes
    Charlie: &Foo{}, // They are not
}

func main() {
    if FooValues.Alpha == FooValues.Charlie {
        panic("enum values are the same!")
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot rely on the value of pointers to an empty struct being meaningful.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way I can force the pointers to be different?

No. Any implementation is allowed to use the same address. You must redesign.

From the Go language [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Pointers to distinct zero-size variables may or may not be equal.

Comment: It seems a mistake to allow equality tests on empty struct pointers then. All trap and no benefit.

Comment: @Fax The problem is not equality on `struct{}` or pointers thereof but you using `struct{}` _at_ _all_. Especially without understanding.

Comment: If one shouldn't use structs in Golang, what should one use instead?

Comment: @Fax I did not say "Do not use structs." I said "Do not use `struct{}`." I'm talking about the empty struct only.

Comment: Interesting. That makes Go the only language I know of where the empty struct is a special case that may only be used by level 45 language wizards. I must have missed that warning in the introductory tutorial.

Comment: The empty struct is not covered by any introductory tutorial, simply because it should not be used. Using it in `map[T]struct{}` instead of `bool` is a low-level performance optimisation and the only valid use of the empty struct.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do it:

```
package main

type foo struct{}

func newFoo() *foo {
   return new(foo)
}

type fooValues struct { alpha, bravo, charlie *foo }

func newFooValues() fooValues {
   return fooValues{
      newFoo(), newFoo(), newFoo(),
   }
}

func main() {
   f := newFooValues()
   if f.alpha == f.charlie {
      panic("enum values are the same!")
   }
}
```

Comment: Good find. Also seems to work with `reflect.New(Foo)`. Of couse, "seems to work" is not sufficient proof in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, pointer comparison for zero-sized types is not reliable in this way.

Replace

```golang
type Foo struct{}
```

with

```golang
type Foo struct{int}
```

Now your code works. The added cost is ~1 word of memory per enum that you allocate, which should be negligible in most cases.

Comment: I'm mainly worried that other developers or future me will forget that empty struct is a pitfall. I might end up with a utility that uses reflection to check the enum and panic if it finds an empty struct. Your suggestion would make a good panic message.